# Creating a Subclass of Page in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

**What I'm attempting to do:**

Create a custom page control that consumers can use just like the UWP page, but, that also displays it's own custom content along side the consumers content.

**What have I tried:**

- Creating a new Control, inheriting from Page
- Creating a templated control that inherits from page
- Creating a control that contains a page
- Setting the `ContentProperty` attribute and binding to it in my custom page

**What is the problem?**

When I attempt to create a control that has both a `xaml` and `xaml.cs` file, that inherits from `Page` I get `InvalidCastExceptions` on random controls inside the subclassed control.

**Example:**

**`TestPage.xaml`**

```
<Page
    x:Class="ControlSandbox.TestPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:uwp_toolkit="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Page.Content>
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" />
    </Page.Content>

    <Page.BottomAppBar>
        <AppBar Background="Transparent" x:Name="appbar" IsOpen="True">
            <uwp_toolkit:InAppNotification x:Name="note">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock>HEADER!</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock>Message</TextBlock>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Button>OK</Button>
                        <Button>Cancel?</Button>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </uwp_toolkit:InAppNotification>
        </AppBar>
    </Page.BottomAppBar>
</Page>
```

**`TestPage.xaml.cs`**

```
public partial class TestPage : Page
{
    public TestPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void ShowNotification()
    {
        appbar.IsOpen = true;
        note.Show();
    }
}
```

**`MainPage.xaml`**

```
<controlsandbox:TestPage
    xmlns:controlsandbox="using:ControlSandbox"    x:Class="ControlSandbox.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" 
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <Button Click="Button_Click">SHOW NOTIFICATION</Button>
    </Grid>

</controlsandbox:TestPage>
```

**`MainPage.xaml.cs`**

```
public partial class MainPage : TestPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.ShowNotification();
    }
}
```

The above code results in an `InvalidCastException` and for the life of me I can't find the problem.

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type
>   'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.AppBar' to type
>   'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button'.'

Now if I do the same exact code, but all in the `MainPage.xaml` instead of in the `TestPage.xaml` everything works as expected

## Update

So I believe this is a bug in the platform. Here is a demo I did of the issue. Please prove me wrong because this would be a real limitation https://github.com/DotNetRussell/UWP_Page_Inheritance_Bug

## Update

I added the changes for the answer below. It seems that when I create a normal templated control and put it on a vanilla uwp page, it works fine. However, when I create a templated `Page`, it ignores my template.

## Update

I think this is a bug in the platform. I opened an issue up on github https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/1075

Comment: From your description, You want to custom page right?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT yeah, I want a custom page that takes the content that the consumer is giving it and combines it with it's own default content. Imagine a control that has other elements like a nav pane, notification bar, context bar, and other things by default. Then you give it your content and it puts it in the middle of that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that if create custom base page with Xaml, it will be mandatory converted to the subpage's content, if the sub-page contained controls different with Base page will throw exception. And the better way is create base class without xaml and add the base page content in the code behind. For more code please refer the following .

```
public class BasePage : Page
{

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {

        this.BottomAppBar = new AppBar()
        {
            Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent),
            IsOpen = false,
            Content = new InAppNotification
            {
                Content = new StackPanel
                {
                    Children =
                    {
                    new TextBlock{ Text = "HEADER!"},
                    new TextBlock{Text = "Message"},
                    new StackPanel
                    {
                        Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal,
                        Children=
                        {
                            new Button{Content = "ok"},
                            new Button {Content = "cancel"}
                        }
                    }

                    }
                }
            }
        };
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    }
    public void ShowNotification()
    {
        this.BottomAppBar.IsOpen = true;
        InAppNotification note = this.BottomAppBar.Content as InAppNotification;
        if (note != null)
            note.Show();
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : BasePage
{
    public MainPage() 
    {        
        this.InitializeComponent();       
    }


    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ShowNotification();
    }
}
```

**Xaml**

```
<local:BasePage
    x:Class="CustomPage.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:CustomPage"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    >

    <Grid>
        <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="ClikMe" />
    </Grid>
</local:BasePage>
```

Comment: I agree this is a work around but generating controls in a CS just to jam into a page probably isn't a recommended pattern. I would expect page to work like any other control that I want to derive from.

Comment: We just init the control in the cs and it does not jam into a page.  if you want to make the base page work like control you could refer  @mm8's replay,

Comment: I'm just not sure why I'm not allowed to modify the Page control template like everything else.

Comment: emm, It is by design, I think xaml is independent part and it could be inherit directly

Answer (score 0):

Create a Templated Control (Project->Add New Item->Templated Control in Visual Studio):

```
public sealed class CustomPage : Page
{
    private AppBar appbar;
    private InAppNotification note;

    public CustomPage()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(CustomPage);
    }

    protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        appbar = GetTemplateChild("appbar") as AppBar;
        note = GetTemplateChild("note") as InAppNotification;
    }

    public void ShowNotification()
    {
        if (appbar != null)
            appbar.IsOpen = true;
        note?.Show();
    }
}
```

...and define a custom `Style` in `Themes/Generic.xaml`:

```
<Style TargetType="local:CustomPage">
    <Setter Property="BottomAppBar">
        <Setter.Value>
            <AppBar Background="Transparent" x:Name="appbar" IsOpen="True">
                <uwp_toolkit:InAppNotification x:Name="note">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock>HEADER!</TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock>Message</TextBlock>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Button>OK</Button>
                            <Button>Cancel?</Button>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </uwp_toolkit:InAppNotification>
            </AppBar>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

There is `.xaml.cs` file for the `CustomPage` base class.

**Edit:** Since the `BottomAppBar` is not part of the template, you need to wait to access the elements in it until they have actually been created. Just do this in the method:

```
public sealed class CustomPage : Page
{
    public CustomPage()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(CustomPage);
    }

    public void ShowNotification()
    {
        AppBar appBar = this.BottomAppBar;
        appBar.IsOpen = true;
        InAppNotification note = appBar.Content as InAppNotification;
        if(note != null)
            note.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you see if this worked by chance with my above example? I mentioned that I did already try a templated control. Curious how this is different

Comment: Just tested this out. `note` and `appbar` are always null

Comment: Also, just to confirm, I have created a test templated control that just has a simple text box in the template style. It works. So there's something else afoot here

Comment: I've reproduced the issue and put it on github so you can see your answer implemented https://github.com/DotNetRussell/UWP_Page_Inheritance_Bug

Comment: Though I appreciate the work around, this really isn't about the bottom app bar. It's about being able to define a custom page that is a container of consumer content. I want to be able to define elements in the main content field that contain and surround the content given by the user. Currently I don't think this is possible with page though it's possible with every other control. I think this is a bug in the platform

Comment: Did you try to add the elements in the `ControlTemplate`? Then `GetTemplateChild` works.

Comment: Yes, it looks like the content is either one or the other. Either it takes the custom content I provide in the  template, or it takes the consumer content. Never both

Comment: The `ContentTemplate` should include a `<ContentPresenter />` element where you want the "consumer content" to show up.

Comment: @AnthonyRussell: So how does your template currently look like?

Comment: Currently, it's what you posted. Please see the linked github repo. I'm using this to track the changes from your post going forward. I spent about 6 hours on this trying different solutions like what we've discussed here and what I posted above.

Comment: @AnthonyRussell: I didn't post a template because I answered before your "this really isn't about the bottom app bar" question.

Comment: I know you didn't, I'm saying that's one of the things that I've tried though. If I get a free min, I'll update the github repo. Just wanted to move the discussion forward since this is something I tried

Comment: @AnthonyRussell: Please show exactly what you have tried and how.

Comment: I added a test page `TestPage2` to that github repo that shows that modifying the control template and adding in a contentpresenter doesn't work

Comment: @AnthonyRussell: I haven't had a chance to try your code but you should not bind to the `ContentPresenter` and not include more than one in the same template. It should simply be defined like this in the XAML:  `<ContentPresenter />`